# spring security : can I pass page scope attributes to spring security tags using EL (or otherwise)?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-3

The following works correctly :

```
<sec:authorize access="canViewUser(AMIT)">
    //SOMETHING TO BE SECURED
</sec:authorize>
```

But, I wish to do something like :

```
<sec:authorize access="canViewUser(${userId})">
    //SOMETHING TO BE SECURED
</sec:authorize>
```

But Spring security tags don't seem to support EL and this gives the error :

> According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute access
>   does not accept any expressions

Any workaround is there by which I can pass page scope attributes to these tags ? Even a scriptlet solution can be considered as a last resort.

Also, where does the TLD mention that it doesn't accept expressions ? I checked the **TLD** file for spring security tags and it didn't seem to indicate this thing anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to write a custom **TLD** file with pretty much the same option as the original spring security tld file, apart from the following lines :

```
<attribute>
            <name>access</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
            <description>
                A Spring-EL expression which is supported by the WebSecurityExpressionHandler
                in the application context. The latter will be used to evaluate the expression.
            </description>
</attribute>
```

which replaces the description of the attribute "access" in the original TLD. Change the **url** attribute too to any other value. This tld, I placed under WEB-INF and used it inside my jsp.

Hopefully, this functionality would be there be default in Spring security in future verstons.